# Mixin a method to an existing module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mixins

I am using `linkedin` module for Rails. I would like to add a method to class `LinkedIn::Mash` in this module. I do add a `mash.rb` file to `/models/concerns` (I am using Rails 4):

```
module LinkedIn
    class Mash
        def my_method
        end
    end
end
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
my_mash_ojbect.respond_to? :my_method #=> false
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
LinkedIn::Mash.instance_eval do
  def my_method
  end
end
```

Have a look at [this](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/metaprogramming-ruby-class-eval-and-instance-eval) if you want to read more about instance_eval or read metaprogramming ruby book